# Determining whether a ring morphism with certain properties is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a finitely generated commutative algebra over a field $K$. Suppose that we are given a morphism $$\varphi \colon K[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to A$$ from the polynomial ring to $A$, such that the ideal $I:=(\varphi(X_1), \ldots, \varphi(X_n)) \subseteq A$ generated by the images of the variables is the intersection of finitely many maximal ideals of $A$, i.e. there exist $\mathfrak m_1, \ldots, \mathfrak m_r \subseteq A$ such that $$I= \bigcap_{i=1}^r \mathfrak m_i.$$

> Question: Is $\varphi$ then necessarily a finite morphism? (By finite I mean that $A$, regarded as a $K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$-module via $\varphi$, is a finitely generated module.)

A proof or a counterexample would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not without more assumptions: let $n=1$, $A=K[t,u]/(tu)$, and $\varphi$ send $X_1\mapsto t-1$. Then $(t-1)$ is maximal, but $A$ is not module-finite over $K[X_1]$. Can you say more about what lead you to this?

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample! Well the question stems from trying to transfer a problem about an affinoid algebra $R$ over a complete nonarchimedean valued field $K$ to a problem regarding its reduction $\widetilde{R}$ which is a finitely generated algebra over the residue field of $K$. Given finitely many max. ideals $\mathfrak{m}_j$ in R, I need to construct a surjective morphism $K \langle  X_1, \ldots, X_n \rangle \to R$ such that the images of the variables (call them $f_i$) satisfy $|f_i \mod \mathfrak{m}_j|<1$. This is equivalent to $\tilde{f_i} \in \cap_j \tilde{\mathfrak{m}}_j$.

Comment: So my idea was to work downstairs in $\tilde R$ and obtain at least a finite morphism $k[X_1, \ldots, X_n] \to \tilde R$, which by a theorem then lifts to a finite morphism $K \langle  X_1, \ldots, X_n \rangle \to R$, which I can then hopefully tweak to make surjective